# PostgreSQL Query: Need to add 7 hours to NOW() to adjust the time to GMT to match the other side of my calcuation

Tags: postgresql

Hello Overflow Community!

Q: Need to add 7 hours to `NOW()` to adjust the time to GMT.  This calculation is being used in the WHERE statement of my query. I am using PostgreSQL in SAP HANA Studio Version: 2.3.28.

I have researched similar questions in Stackoverflow and used variations of syntax found in my research, but I cannot get past SQL syntax errors.

I cannot identify what is incorrect about my my approach. Can someone help me fix this query?

```
`SELECT 
   a.ACCOUNTID,
   a.CASENUMBER, 
   a.ID,
   a.STATUS,
   a.SUBJECT,
   a.CREATEDDATE_GMT,
   b.NAME,
   b.OWNERID` 

`FROM "SFDC"."CASE" AS a
LEFT JOIN "SFDC"."GROUP" AS b ON a.OWNERID = b.ID` 

`WHERE CAST(a.CREATEDDATE_GMT AS DATE) = CAST(DATEADD('hour', 7, NOW()) AS DATE);
```

`

I also tried these other 4 variation in my WHERE statement, but received syntax errors.

`CAST(a.CREATEDDATE_GMT AS DATE) = ADD_DAYS(hour, 7, CAST(NOW()AS DATE))
    CAST(a.CREATEDDATE_GMT AS DATE) = CAST(NOW()AS DATE) + CAST((7 || ' hours') AS INTERVAL)
    CAST(a.CREATEDDATE_GMT AS DATE) = CAST(NOW()AS DATE) + INTERVAL '7 hours'`

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are asking. Please give some sample data and the expected result. There are no functions `dateadd` and `add_days` in PostgreSQL. Adding a `date` and an `interval` will result in a `timestamp without time zone`.

Comment: Do not add hours to _adjust_ timezone, use `AT TIME ZONE` clause instead: `SELECT NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'`;

Comment: Hi Laurenz and Michel...thank you very much for your responses.  They helped.   My calculation is in the WHERE statement where I needed to covert the current system time and date on the right side of the equation to GMT/UTC.   I tried the following and appears to have worked.                                                                                                        WHERE 
    CAST(a.CREATEDDATE_GMT AS DATE) <= CAST(CURRENT_UTCDATE AS DATE)
ORDER BY a.CREATEDDATE_GMT DESC